# Install application for testing with out Apple MFI Program

Tags: ios, mfi

Is it possible to install my bluetooth based application for testing without Apple MFI Program?

Comment: It is, but unless you are enrolled in the mfi program or have access to other mfi certified hardware, your app will not be able to see legacy Bluetooth hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should be able to use TestFlight or HockeyApp to distribute the app to testers.
I believe you can also create and install the .IPA file for the app if you have the UDID of the device you are adding it to.